# Convert a string to date in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am using SSIS derived column for an ETL process and I need to convert the string "1982 May 06 12:00:00  AM" to YYYY-MM-DD ("1982-05-06")

This is my attempt:

```cs
 LEFT(REPLACE(LEFT( [fechaexpedicion] ,11)," ","-"),5)+ MONTH([fechaexpedicion] ) +SUBSTRING(REPLACE(LEFT( [fechaexpedicion] ,11)," ","-"),9,3)
```

But the problem is that month doesn't get the month from a string type, so I haven't been able to convert the month to numeric.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not just convert to to a date (and time) data type?

Comment: This will be imported into another database which is not capable of doing the conversion

Comment: The other database isn't capable of storing a date and time data type..?

Comment: Yes, but I need the format YYYY-MM-DD, I Dont need time

Comment: Ok but both SSIS and SQL Server have a date data type (`dt_dbdate` and `date` respectively), so why don't you want to use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to be using SQL Server 2012 or later, it looks like SQL Server's `TRY_CONVERT()` function can handle your format:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, '1982 May 06 12:00:00 AM');  -- 1982-05-06
```

Comment: But i need to do this for all the elements in the column

Comment: Then replace the datetime literal with the column name.

Comment: This work, How can I replace the values ​​of the query with all the elements of the column?

Comment: Instead of `'1982 May 06 12:00:00 AM'` it would be `YourColumn` where `YourColumn` is the **name** of *your column*, @wessi .

Comment: I totally understand that, only this doesn't change the values ​​of my column, it just gives me a query that doesn't change the values

Comment: Yes it does; `'1982 May 06 12:00:00 AM''` is a `varchar` value, where as the result of the above would be a `date`, which would be consumed by the application as a binary value, and would have *no* time portion.